# ngFor creating columns but not showing data

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am very new to ionic/angular and am having issues with ngFor. Right now the ngFor below creates columns and cards as expected but no data from my **items** array is showing in the cards. I'm confused as to why the columns/cards are created but then the {{items.key}} data isn't being displayed in them. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

(Also, this is my first question on here so please let me know if I've used incorrect tags or anything)

html file:

```
<ion-content>
<ion-grid>
<ion-row wrap>
  <ion-col *ngFor="let item of items" >
    <ion-card>
      <img src="assets/icon/tuneImage.png" />
      <ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-subtitle></ion-card-subtitle>
        <ion-card-title>{{items.key}}</ion-card-title>
      </ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-content>
      </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
</ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

.ts file:

```
export class Page2Page implements OnInit {
 public items:any;
 data: Observable<any>;

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
        var url = 'https://thesession.org/tunes/new?format=json';
        this.data = this.http.get(url);
        this.data.subscribe(data =>{
        this.items  = Object.assign([], data.settings);
        //console.log(this.items[1].key);
        })
        }
  }
```

[I've attached an image below of the cards currently which aren't displaying the {{items.key}} value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dvi9L.png)

Comment: I guess it should be `item.key`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the key is a property of each item, not a property of the array of items. So it should be `item.key`, not `items.key`.

You should really, really avoid using the `any` type everywhere. Using the correct types would make this more obvious. And compiling in the AOT mode would even produce an error rather than just displaying nothing.

Comment: Ah thanks! I can't believe I've missed that now and I see, I'll avoid "any" from now on.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things.

(i) You can simply assign settings as it is returning data as an array. Also, you should use the correct type when you are binding the data. You can use [`JSON2TS`](http://json2ts.com/) to create a model for your type.

```
  this.items  = data.settings;
```

(ii) It should be **`item.key`** instead of items.key as you have the object in the **`item`**.

```
<ion-col *ngFor="let item of items" >
    <ion-card>
      <img src="assets/icon/tuneImage.png" />
      <ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-subtitle></ion-card-subtitle>
        <ion-card-title>{{item.key}}</ion-card-title>
      </ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-content>
      </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
</ion-col>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response as well! I'm shocked I didn't see the items.key was incorrect